# Template and const

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I guess what I'm trying to do it's impossible but I have this code:

```
 22 class Q
 21 {   
 22     int integer;
 23     int fractional;
 24     int word;
 25   public:
 26     Q(int i,int f) { this->integer = i; this->fractional = f; this->word = i+f;}
 27     const int get_i() {return (const int)this->integer;}
 28     const int get_f() {return (const int)this->fractional;}
 29     const int get_w() {return (const int)this->word;}
 30     
 31     friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Q& q){ os << "Q" << q.integer << "." << q.fractional << " (w:" << q.word << ")"; return os; }
 32 };
 33 
 34 
 35 const Q Q1_i = Q(1,10);
 36 const Q Q1_o = Q(0,11);
 37 
 38 const std::array<Q,1> input_queue_q = {Q1_i};
 39 const std::array<Q,1> output_queue_q = {Q1_o};
 40 
 41 
 42 int sc_main(int argc, char *argv[])
 43 { 
 44   ac_fixed<Q1_i.get_w(),1,false,AC_TRN,AC_SAT> mem;
 45   
 46   for(const Q &input_q : input_queue_q)
 47   { 
 48     for(const Q &output_q : output_queue_q)
 49     { 
 50       ac_fixed<input_q.get_w(),1,false,AC_TRN,AC_SAT> mem;
 51     }
 52   }
 53 }
```

When I try to compile I got the following error:

```
check_ac_one_over.cpp: In function ‘int sc_main(int, char**)’:
check_ac_one_over.cpp:44:23: error: passing ‘const Q’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘const int Q::get_w()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   ac_fixed<Q1_i.get_w(),1,false,AC_TRN,AC_SAT> mem;
                       ^
check_ac_one_over.cpp:44:23: error: call to non-constexpr function ‘const int Q::get_w()’
check_ac_one_over.cpp:44:23: error: call to non-constexpr function ‘const int Q::get_w()’
check_ac_one_over.cpp:44:46: note: in template argument for type ‘int’ 
   ac_fixed<Q1_i.get_w(),1,false,AC_TRN,AC_SAT> mem;
                                              ^
check_ac_one_over.cpp:44:51: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
   ac_fixed<Q1_i.get_w(),1,false,AC_TRN,AC_SAT> mem;
                                                   ^
check_ac_one_over.cpp:50:30: error: passing ‘const Q’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘const int Q::get_w()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       ac_fixed<input_q.get_w(),1,false,AC_TRN,AC_SAT> mem;
                              ^
check_ac_one_over.cpp:50:30: error: call to non-constexpr function ‘const int Q::get_w()’
check_ac_one_over.cpp:50:30: error: call to non-constexpr function ‘const int Q::get_w()’
check_ac_one_over.cpp:50:53: note: in template argument for type ‘int’ 
       ac_fixed<input_q.get_w(),1,false,AC_TRN,AC_SAT> mem;
                                                     ^
check_ac_one_over.cpp:50:58: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
       ac_fixed<input_q.get_w(),1,false,AC_TRN,AC_SAT> mem;
                                                          ^
make: *** [check_ac_one_over.o] Error 1
```

I guess the problem is that gcc think that Q1_i.get_w() can change. Is there a way to compile this code ? I would like to iterate and use that templated type using the class that I've defined above.

Cheers,
Stefano.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make your code "const correct".  Currently it is:

```
const int get_w() {return (const int)this->word;}
```

Returning a value as `const` is useless, because modifications to a value do not reflect anywhere else.  But you failed to make the method `const`, meaning it does not change `this`.  It should be:

```
int get_w() const {return word;}
```

The `const` following the parentheses means that the method will not modify any member variables (except those marked `mutable`, which are usually none).

Comment: Being used as a template parameter, doesn't `get_w` need to be explicitly marked as `constexpr` if it wants to be used as such?

Comment: @Vivick I guess you are right, now the problem is that : check_ac_one_over.cpp:44:23: error: call to non-constexpr function ‘const int Q::get_w() const’
Ideas ?

Comment: If `word` is mutable then you cannot use it in a template. If it is not mutable, you should be able to pass it as a template parameter of `Q` instead of a member and write `get_w` as a `constexpr`

Comment: word is not mutable but it should be calculated in the constructor of the Q class. I would like to avoid to pass it as a template if possible.

Comment: I've managed to fix that problem changing the code, but I'm still stuck. The problem now is when I do the iteration of the arrays : https://nopaste.xyz/?fd343ad64989f297#40qdVnh2EvkBsl/7H7/lPHElT0QA+sUcqt5AQDWGDjQ=

Comment: Sorry for the spam. I guess the root of the problem is the for loop. I'm reading that there is no way to evaluate and unroll a loop at compile time. This means that whatever trick I can use every template that rely on a variable derived by the index in the loop can't be properly evaluated at compile time. Am I right ?